# Java8 lambda sequential or piped String transformation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I work on a JCR- based application, and my query breaks when it contains illegal characters.

So I've undertaken a really simple task: given a query string and a map containing a list of "dodgy" characters, sequentially replace those dodgy chars with allowed ones. I want to use lambdas, and am sadly a little bit stuck:

```
public static Map<String, String> DODGY_CHARS = getDodgyCharMapping();

static Map<String, String> getDodgyCharMapping(){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("'", "''");
    return map;
}

private String sanitizeQueryString(String query){
    DODGY_CHARS.keySet().forEach(key->{
        query = replaceCharacter(query, key, DODGY_CHARS.get(key));
    });
    return query;
}
```

The **query** variable inside the lambda is what J8 is not happy with, resulting in the following error:

```
error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
```

Comment: Well - the error message says it, in your lambda you may only use final variables from the outer scope...? Why not just use a traditional for-each loop?

Comment: Declaring it finlal (or declaring a second, final, variable) doesn't do any good either and well, I thought lambdas are the way forward, so I decided to give it a go...

Comment: Why do you want to use lambdas? Just iterate across the characters (once) and build a new `StringBuilder` from the transformed versions. Not every task lends itself to lambdas, and this is one of them.

Comment: It seems that if your query string contains `''`, you will end up with `''''` after this method is invoked.

Comment: Good point scottb!

Comment: You might look into guava's CharMatcher, using CharMatcher::anyOf to create a matcher that matches all of your dodgy characters, then using CharMatcher::replaceFrom to replace all of the dodgy characters in any string you pass in.

Comment: Just another, unrelated remark: there’s `Map.forEach(…)` which accepts a `BiConsumer` that will receive both, key and value, i.e. `DODGY_CHARS.forEach( (key,value) -> … );`. It makes no sense to use `.keySet().forEach(…)` instead, to consume the keys only and perform an entirely obsolete lookup operation via `get` within the `Consumer` *for every key*…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're accessing the local variable `query` within the scope of the lambda expression's body. It therefore must be `final` or effectively `final`. However, declaring `query` as `final` would not solve the problem since you're assigning a value to it.

I would suggest you let the method `replaceCharacter` takes a `StringBuilder` and have it replace the contents instead of reading and re-assigning the `String` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for useful replies and comments, good people. 
Yes, I started digging deeper - and have tried to use StringBuilder, but since I needed to replace all occurrencies within a string, that quickly escalated to 10+ lines of code with another nested loop.

Thus, instead of reducing complexity and improving code readability, that was doing right the opposite.

Compare to the lambda-free one:

```
private String sanitizeQueryString(String query){
    for (String key: DODGY_CHARS.keySet()){
        query = replaceCharacter(query, key, DODGY_CHARS.get(key));
    }
    return query;
}
```

Nice and simple, huh?

Lesson learnt: don't try to shoe-horn everything as lambda, no matter how 
fashionable these are!

Comment: Reserve lambdas for those situations in which you really do need to "send code as data".  If you want to send a function as an argument to a method, then you're looking at a lambda-rich environment.

Comment: I guess your map is rather small, so it wouldn't make much difference. However in general, you should iterate over the map's `entrySet()` if you need to access both the key and the value, in order to avoid the lookup.